# How can I load fast a xib view into my viewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, xib

I have a xib in my objective c application. But when I'm trying to load this viewController, this spend around 1 second, and this is a bad feeling...

I'm using a custom font, but I have added this correctly to my .plist
My customView class is added by file's owner  and connected with the outlets.

My code is:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

    if (self)
    {
        nibname=@"MyCustomView";

        [self addSubview:
        [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:nibname
                                       owner:self
                                     options:nil] objectAtIndex:0]];


    }
    return self;
}
```

And then, I load this in my viewController like this:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    ...
    MyCustomXib *myview = [[MyCustomXib alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 600)];
    [self.view addSubview:myview];
    ...
}
```

Am I loading this custom view correctly?

How can I do this process of loading faster?

**Edit 1** corrected then read matt comment:

```
[self.view addSubview:myview];
```

to supply: last wrong code: [self.view myview];

Comment: This is not your real code. The line `[self.view myview];` makes no sense whatever.

Comment: ¿? really I'm adding this to uiscrollView, but for do more simple this example I add this to the view. What happen? It's work too....

Comment: You didn't add anything to anything. If you meant to say `addSubview:` you should _say_ it. Supply _real_ code, not just some stuff you type freehand. _Copy and paste_ from a real test project.

Comment: Sorry for this, but I have change my code then, to add this into self.view and work like adding to scroll, for this reason I decided show my example in self.view... It's could be more easy..

Comment: You are not listening to what I'm saying. An actual line `[self.view myview];` won't compile. It is nonsense. It isn't Objective-C.

Comment: oh sorry, I didn't see this worst error. I corrected this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't reproduce the problem based on what you've said. I added timings to your `viewDidAppear` code:

```
NSLog(@"%f", [[NSDate new] timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]);
MyCustomXib *myview = [[MyCustomXib alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 600)];
[self.view addSubview:myview];
NSLog(@"%f", [[NSDate new] timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]);
```

And here's the output:

```
2017-01-24 12:47:18.812 NibLoadTest[12087:135969] 506983638.811982
2017-01-24 12:47:18.814 NibLoadTest[12087:135969] 506983638.814367
```

That is *not* a delay of 1 second! It is a couple of *thousandths* of a second.

Thus the problem is illusory or is caused by something else you have not shown. If you're trying to measure how long something is taking, *measure* it. Ideally, use Instruments; that what it's for. It will tell what is taking time *and why*. Do not guess.

Comment: It also seems risky to put this code in `viewDidAppear`, as this may be called many times over the lifetime of this view controller, thus causing the same view to be added again and again.

Comment: A lot of thanks! @matt this is the correct answer. I have change my code to the viewDidLoad function and this work correctly without delay. The problem was that you comment, is called many times in the viewDidAppear. Happy coding! Thanks!